# Is it better to develop App with Unity or Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I started developing the prototype for my first Android Gaming App. The App itself is acutally not Gaming orientated (which is the reason why I started developing with AS), but I want to add some Mini Games (2D) afterwards, which will be developed in Unity.

Since I am new to Android Studio, I was wondering if it would be better to develop the whole prototype in Unity, basically to avoid exporting the Mini Games to an existing Android Studio project. Otherwise circa 80% of the app will be non - gaming (interacting with clans and other users) and AS might be the better option for fast results.

I would be happy if someone would help me with a quick piece of advise.
Thank you!

Comment: Unity for sure, there's even a [game development page](https://developer.android.com/games/develop/build-in-unity) on the Android Developer portal that specifically recommends it.

Comment: Well if 80% of your app is non-game I would go native Kotlin or Java in AS and add the unity part as a plugin. I wrote an article on how to do that https://medium.com/@razvan_57516/how-to-embed-unity-3d-in-a-native-android-app-5d030673bbf4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just been trough the experience of porting a game from Unity to Kotlin due to restrictions and struggles with using Unity.

You should go for Kotlin (Android Studio) route if you need one of the following:

**Hardware / Sensor-capabilities**
The most common sensors are supported by unity, but if you need odd-case sensors like NFC you would need to use [Android plug-ins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) or an existing library from the asset-store. I have had really bad experience with outdated libraries from the asset store, and creating your own plugins often require that you need to have a Kotlin-project anyways.

**Android-like UI**
Unity does not have integrated support for native android UI-elements so you would have to create your own UI in unity. The biggest issue I experienced with trying to imitate Android-UI in unity was that it is noticably slower and more sluggish user-experience than if it was done natively (For example, creating a scrollview in Unity feels extremely sluggish.) The slowness can also be related to the fact that a Unity-application will refresh the entire screen for every frame, while native Kotlin have support for partial rendering. (You can test that with the debug-option in the Android Developer menu on the phone.) That would be more visible on lower-end phones and will have an impact on power-usage.

**Accessibility**
[Unity does not support screenreaders on Smartphones](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1248230/ios-and-android-accessibility.html) due to how the UI is rendered, and unless you want to use the time to add that support yourself, [there is a plugin that does it for 75 bux](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/ui-accessibility-plugin-uap-87935). By using native Android UI you wont have this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the substantial response. That seems reasonabel, AS with Kotlin will be the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer

If you are Developing games go for unreal or unity

But if you want to make Apps go for Android Studio